# Proof that a given projection map restricted to a subset is closed.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

$\pi_{1}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto x$ is a projection map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard eulcidean topology, $\mathscr{T}_E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with it's usual euclidean topology $\mathscr{T}_\mathbb{R}$.

Let $X:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\;|\; xy=0\}$ (the axes effectively), endowed with the subspace topology $\mathscr{T}_X$ and let $p:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the restriction of $\pi_1$ to $X$. Show that $p$ is closed, i.e. for each V closed in $(X,\mathscr{T}_X)$, $p(V)$ is closed in $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{T}_\mathbb{R})$.

Attempt:

---

So the way I would attempt it for open maps at least is to choose a basis for the topology.
Here, $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}_1 \cup \mathcal{B}_2$ <strike>is a basis</strike> for $\mathscr{T}_X$, where:

$\mathcal{B}_1:=\{(\alpha,\beta)\times\ \{0\}\;|\; \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha<\beta\}$

$\mathcal{B}_2:=\{\{0\}\times(\alpha,\beta) \;|\; \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha<\beta\}$

So I considered taking the complement of the elements in <strike>the basis</strike> with respect to X, to form <strike>a basis</strike> $\mathcal{A}$ say, for the closed sets of the topology, $\mathcal{A}:=\{X\backslash U\;|\;U \in \mathcal{B}\}$.

Then consider $p(V)$ for $V$ in $\mathcal{A}$. For $V=X\backslash U$ where $U \in \mathcal{B}_2$, $p(V)=\mathbb{R}$, and for  $V=X\backslash U$ where $U \in \mathcal{B}_1$, $p(V)=(\mathbb{R}\backslash (\alpha,\beta)) \cup \{0\}$. In both cases the sets are closed.

But, for sets $U_\lambda, \lambda \in \Lambda$ an indexing set, and $f$ a map, $f(\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda} U_\lambda)=\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f(U_\lambda)$. So when proving certain things about open sets reduces to proving it for a basis, and I am assuming because of the corresponding image rule: 
$f(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda} U_\lambda)\subseteq\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f(U_\lambda)$, that I can't conclude the map is closed using the basis for closed sets?

Cheers for any help. I'd rather hints on approaches as opposed to full solutions, but a comment on the use of basis would be appreciated.

Comment: Your basis $\mathcal{B}$ is not quite a basis. For example, the set $(-1,1)\times\{0\}$ is not open in $X$.

Comment: @wckronholm You're right, I completely forgot about the intersections at the origin. Cheers, I will keep working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $X$ is just the union of $x$ and $y$-axes alongwith the origin. Now any closed set in $X$ w.r.t. to subspace topology is $C\cap X$ where $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. If $C$ doesn't intersect the $x$-axis at all then the corresponding intersection with $X$ will yield sets of the form $\{(0,y) \ |y\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and hence when you'll take projection then the image will be $0$ which is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. If $C$ intersect $x$-axis then the corresponding image after taking projection will be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ as the intersection of $C$ with $x$-axis will give some closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Its instructive to draw pictures while solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the lemma:

> Let $X,Y$ be spaces, $X=C\cup D$ for subspaces $C,D$ of $X$, and $f:X\to Y$ a set map. If $f|_C:C\to Y , f|_D:D\to Y$ are closed restrictions of $f$, then $f$ is a closed map.

Comment: I don't think I've come across this before, but it looks to be very helpful, thank you. Would this be covered in many introductory books on topology do you know? Apologies for a very delayed response, I took a break from doing topology assignments for a while.

Comment: I doesn't appear in any book I know of, and I think it's even too trivial to be mentioned as a theorem or so. Can you prove it yourself? The idea is to use the fact that the image of a union is the union of the images.